# Certain properties don't transfer over from external style sheet

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

So I'm currently designing a website, and I'm using the same CSS for every page.  Originally, I had it included in each individual document, however it got annoying having to change it on every page, so instead I set them all to work off an external style sheet.  Now, it worked for the most part, however a couple properties stopped working, namely text-align and float.  What's weird is that if you include those properties in an internal style sheet, it starts working again.  I'm guessing it has to do with some sort of priority thing, but I'm wondering why those specific properties don't work, and if there's any way of specifying those properties in an external style sheet.  Thanks!

CSS:

```
    div.box1
    {
        border-width:0px;
        text-align:left
    }
    img.floatLeft
    { 
        float: left; 
        margin: 5px;  
    }

    img.floatRight
    { 
        float: right;  
        margin: 5px;  
     }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box1">
<font face="helvetica">
    TEXT TEXT TEXT <br><br><br>
    <b>NAME</b>
    <br>
    <img src="NAME" class="floatRight">
    TEXT TEXT TEXT<br><br>
    <b>NAME2</b>
    <br>
    <img src="NAME2" width="214" height="130" class="floatLeft">
    TEXT TEX TEXT
</font>
</div>
```

Comment: you are missing a `;` in your stylesheet.

Comment: There is a typo `text-align:left` no `;` in the stylesheet

Comment: you should also extract `width="214" height="130"` to your css stylesheet and the same with fonts

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo at `text-align:left`. You are missing a semicolon ; to terminate the statement. Rest is fine.

Your left floated image does not have any attribute `src`, `height` or `width` so it will basically not show itself in the DOM.

See a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/A9WUJ/1/)

Comment: but that is the last attribute in the class, i don't think that does matters

Comment: @palsingh, I am not sure if that will cause the problem but check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/A9WUJ/1/) It shows everything the OP is doing is right

Comment: I agree what OP is doing is right, but a missing semi-colon is irrelevant in this case as it is instantly succeeded by the closing `}`, which terminates the whole style declaration.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, when I posted this my brain was a little fried, however I did try it with and without the semicolon, and it worked both ways.  I just forgot to include it in the version I posted.

Comment: @Adam, Its okay. Glad your problem is solved. Now accept an suitable answer to your post and get going. :)

Comment: Wow, sorry, my brain must still be a little fried.  By "worked" I meant "didn't work equally well", so regardless of whether or not I used the semicolon, everything worked except for those two properties.

Comment: @Adam, I think you should post a fiddle or demo page showing your problem. I don't see other way of solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

The missing semicolon on the last property in a rule is no problem at all. Some css minimizers will do the same.
\
I would rather point out that < font face="helvetica"> should be replaced with a < p>(and matching < /p>.

Comment: Good call.  I actually ended up putting everything in a <p> to see if that helped, but sadly it didn't.  Ah well...